# Android- Multiple Spinners

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, spinner

I have this code:

```
package lijap.app.starcraft2counters;

import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Settings extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
Spinner answertime;
Spinner gametime;
Spinner missesallowed;

String[] answerseconds = { "Unlimited", "1 second", "2 seconds", "3 seconds",
        "4 seconds", " 5 seconds" };

String[] gameminutes = { "Unlimited", "1 minute", "2 minutes", "3 minutes",
        "4 minutes", " 5 minutes" };

String[] numberofmisses = { "Unlimited", "5", "10", "15",
        "20", "25" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Settings.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, gameminutes);

    answertime = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s_answertime);
    answertime.setAdapter(adapter);
    answertime.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

I am getting confused trying to put in more than 1 spinner. Do I share the array adapter, or do I create a new one for each? What about the onItemSelected? As you can see from my strings at the top, I want three spinners. How would I do this?

I am new to android, as you can tell. All help is appreciated- Lijap

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could share the adapter between different `Spinner`s if they adapted the same information. Clearly each of your adapters need to adapt a different set of `String`s, so you need to create an `ArrayAdapter` for each `Spinner`.

A single `OnItemSelectedListener` will work for the 3 `Spinners` (as long as you set them). You can call `getId()` on the `AdapterView<?>` passed as an argument to know which `Spinner` raised the event.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    switch(arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.s_answertime:
            break;
        case ...
    }
}
```

Comment: A different onItemSelected also?

Comment: you saved my day I was doing view.getId() and cracking my head why it was not working

Answer (score 7):

Check this one

```
yearDropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) 
    {
        selectedyear = parentView.getSelectedItemPosition();
        drpyear      = yearDropdown.getSelectedItem().toString();

        //your code here

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) 
    {
        selectedyear = 0;
        //return;
    }
});

monthDropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) 
    {
        //your code here


    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) 
    {
        selectedmonth = 0;
        //return;
    }
});

dayDropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) 
    {
        //your code here

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) 
    {
        selectedday = 0;
    }
});
```

you need to create each adapter for every spinner.

```
   adapterYear = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
   yearDropdown.setAdapter(adapterYear);

   adapterMonth = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
   monthDropdown.setAdapter(adapterMonth);

   adapterDays = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
   dayDropdown.setAdapter(adapterDays);
```