# get which spinner is clicked

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I took multiple spinners in single view. I know how to get when item is selected.

```
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) 
    {

        parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

But how can i know that which spinner user has clicked on in a single listener?
Any suggestion will be appreciated. 
Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following way.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {
    switch(parent.getId()){
        case R.id.spinner1:
            //your code goes here
            break;
        case R.id.spinner2:
            //your code goes here
            break;
    }
}
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777977/android-multiple-spinners) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150834/multiple-spinners-simple-doubts) too.

Answer (score 1):

`parent` in `onItemClick` refers to the Spinner that was clicked.

[AdapterView.OnItemSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html#onItemSelected%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29)

> *parent* The AdapterView where the selection happened

Spinner is an AdapterView. [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html)