# How to set multiple Spinner in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-spinner

I want to build an Android app named Unit Converter. In this app there will be a parent spinner where the user can select what type of unit conversion they want, e.g. `Conversion Type (Temperature)`. Below the parent conversion spinner, there are two child spinners, e.g. `From: Fahrenheit Input, To: Kelvin Output`.

Also there are 3 buttons:

- <kbd>Reset</kbd> for reset the input text field,
- <kbd>Swap</kbd> for swapping child spinners and
- <kbd>Convert</kbd> for converting input value to the desired unit output.

Any similar helpful tutorials/documentation/code samples/web links are appreciated.

Note: I have never used nested spinner. I have also searched a several websites but could not find what I am expecting.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is not a place to get other people to write code for you. SO is a place to get help with code that you have written. I encourage you to try solving this problem yourself , then coming back if you encounter a specific problem. Also check out the [Android Getting Started guide](http://developer.android.com/about/start.html) if this is your first time trying to create an Android app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777977/android-multiple-spinners ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO the definition of "parent" and "children" spinner is quite misleading here. You're basically asking to update the model of the second and third spinner when the value of the first one changes.

What I would do is to implement such a listener for the first spinner and to change the adapter for the second and the third inside the `onItemSelected` method.

```
    public class SpinnerChangeListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {

           String conversionType = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

           // here you've to perform the model update of the second 
           // and third spinner based on the value of conversionType

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
          // Do nothing.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yo're welcome. If you find it useful you may mark the answer as accepted to inform other potential readers. Anyway have fun with Android programming :)

Comment: Will u plz elaborate the code so that I can understand, what is happening@ elbuild